# Spark Streaming write to Kafka with delay - after x minutes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

We have a spark Streaming application.
Architecture is as follows

Kinesis to Spark to Kafka.

The Spark application is using qubole/kinesis-sql for structured streaming from Kinesis. The data is then aggregated and then pushed to Kafka.

Our use case demands a delay of 4 minutes before pushing to Kafka.

The windowing is done with 2 minutes and watermark of 4 minutes

```
val windowedCountsDF = messageDS
   .withWatermark("timestamp", "4 minutes")
   .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "2 minutes", "2 minutes"), $"id", $"eventType", $"topic")
```

Write to Kafka is triggered every two minutes

```
val eventFilteredQuery = windowedCountsDF
  .selectExpr("topic", "id as key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
  .writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 minutes"))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkPoint)
  .outputMode("update")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers)
  .queryName("events_kafka_stream")
  .start()
```

I can change the trigger time to match the window , but still some events gets pushed to kafka instantly.

Is there any way to delay writes to Kafka  x minutes after the window is completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your output mode from `update` to `append` (the default option). The `output` mode will write all updated rows to the sink, hence, if you use a watermark or not will not matter.

However, with the [`append`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) mode any writes will need wait until the watermark is crossed - which is exactly what you want:

> Append mode uses watermark to drop old aggregation state. But the output of a windowed aggregation is delayed the late threshold specified in `withWatermark()` as by the modes semantics, rows can be added to the Result Table only once after they are finalized (i.e. after watermark is crossed).

Comment: @JeensonEphraim Happy to help :)